# Bashscript upload files to hdfs

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to create a bashscript to upload files from the local edge node filesystem to hdfs. I was wondering a good way to add the timestamp in the file. Having some problems with getting timestamp to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Running upload script to hdfs...
timestamp(){date +"%T"}

hdfs dfs -put /home/myname/folder1/* /user/myname/example_1_$(timestamp).txt
hdfs dfs -put /home/myname/folder2/* /user/myname/example_2_$(timestamp).txt
```

Comment: Are you expecting the result pattern to be `example_1_11:20:15.txt`?

Comment: Yeah or something with a timestamp in the filename

Comment: `:` is not possible. Check below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `date +%T` is not possible as the command result would contain `:` characters in it like `11:12:45`, and creating filenames with `:` character is not possible in HDFS. See [Hadoop-3275](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3257).

Try this command in the script,

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/myname/folder1/* /user/myname/example_1_`date +%H%M%S`.txt
```

This will create filename like `/user/myname/example_1_111245.txt`.